# "Discussion" tag in meta is probably redundant

Tags: discussion

How's that for meta?

But seriously, aren't most of the topics in here "discussion"?  Unless they're bugs, I guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would be status-bydesign.

The meta site is intended to be where we discuss the site itself, but it is also where users would connect with the Community Moderators, and System Developers. To make working easier for those people Meta sites have a few mandatory tags.

- Discussion (For General Discussion of the site)
- Feature-Request (for making a feature request)
- Support (for asking for help from a moderator / developer / helpful person)
- Bug (For reporting what you believe to be a bug)

This allows the staff to focus their time when they need to, if you have the 'fix bugs' task for the day the discussions can get in the way. So you'd just search for the 'bug' tag. Also it allows them to keep a running count of the amount of Requests for Support, new features, or bug checks.

For example, this quick search shows the bugs that haven't been assigned a status on Meta.SO

https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/%5Bbug%5D+-%5Bstatus-completed%5D+-%5Bstatus-norepro%5D+-%5Bstatus-declined%5D+-%5Bstatus-deferred%5D+-%5Bstatus-bydesign%5D+-%5Bstatus-review%5D